# Do level layouts change based on number of players?

Tags: zelda-four-swords

I am playing Zelda: Four Swords on GBA with 3 players. We got had trouble on Talos Cave and went to check a guide. However, [a video of the dungeon with 4 players](https://youtu.be/4W-5UV1PQmQ) seemed to have a different layout than the one we played.

Do the dungeon layouts change based on the number of players?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do.

According to [Zelda wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Four_Swords#Gameplay):

> The number of players playing the game, as well as which epic they are playing through, affects the type of random areas and items that will appear during a playthrough.

Comment: The wiki makes it seem like the dungeons are always randomized, even if you have the same number of players.